# Confidence interval for all rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have the following data frame and I would like to construct confidence interval for the mean value of each row (10 CIs altogether):

```
var1<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var2<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var3<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var4<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var5<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var6<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var7<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var8<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var9<-rnorm(10,100,5)
var10<-rnorm(10,100,5)
df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10)
```

I would be thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: How do you calculate confidence interval? Do you have the formula? `sapply` will work on each column, also `apply(X, MARGIN = 2, ...)` will work on each column at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this?:

```
apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(x){mean(x)+c(-1.96,1.96)*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))})
```

of course you can extend the example easily to others than 95%-CIs...

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(x) ci(x))
```

Comment: this is perfect, just need install "gmodels" package.